# How to get allstrings with partial absence word

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have following sample strings, I want get all strings that do not end with Label by using **Regular Expression ie Regex in .Net**.

ID="FirstNameLabel" 
ID="FirstNameTextBox"
ID="LastNameLabel" 
ID="LastNameTextBox"
ID="CountryLabel"
ID="CountryDropDownList"

Basically, I want the result to be

ID="FirstNameTextBox"
ID="LastNameTextBox"
ID="CountryDropDownList"

Does anyone know how to?

To Mark Byers,

I am not getting anything from your regular expression

[image]

Comment: Is the value of the string `FirstNameLabel` or `ID="FirstNameLabel"`? Are the strings in a list?

Comment: Actually, I want to get like ID\=".*?TextBox" and ID\=".*?DropDownList"

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to call the regular expression engine? It might be that your bug is there.

Comment: Hi Mark Byers, Please see my update from screen. I don't have any source code. I am just using regular expression to test it.

Comment: I am doing this, because I need to parse a large number of asp.net page fields. The naming convention is anything that ends with Label is just for display only. So all I need is filter out Label, Extender, RequiredValidator.. etc.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest is to just use `EndsWith`.

```
!s.EndsWith("Label\"")
```

If you really want to use regex, use a lookbehind.

```
"(?<!Label\")$"
```

Comment: if @rerun's answer works, then the expression in this answer should probably be `(?<!\Label)$` **NOT** `(?<!\Label\")$`

Answer (score 0):

```
lines.where((x)=> !x.EndsWith("Label"));
```

If you have to have regex

```
lines.where((x)=> !Regex.Match(x,"Label$").Success);
```